# DataStax Cassandra on Amazon AIM, setup up specific version

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax

I am setting up a Cassandra cluster on Amazon using the DataStax provided AIM (from the list at https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installAMILaunch.html)

This all works perfectly, however it results in the latest version of Cassandra 2.1.3 up and running.

For various reasons I need to use the v2.0.x branch.

Does anyone know how to specify the version of Cassandra to version 2.0 that is deployed?

For example, could it be set via the cluster settings when launching the AIM? perhaps in the `--version community` setting?

Or is there a previous AIM that can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the `--release version` switch

See [advanced switches](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMIlaunch.html) for the AMI.

Comment: Thanks that's great. Do you know if it works for the community edition as well? So the AIM switches would look something like..

--clustername myDSCcluster --totalnodes 6 --version community --release 2.0.11

Comment: I believe it should work for community as well. Let us know and I'll work to update the docs.

Comment: Thanks phact, I'll rebuild the cluster and post back results.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Adding the --release 2.0.11 switch with --version community does setup the specified version. 

thanks for your help phact